# Statistics test on dictionary values

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, graph, scipy

I have some basic code below which tests for normal distribution:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
results = stats.normaltest([various numbers manually inputted])
z,pval = results
if(pval < 0.05):
    print "Data is not normally distributed"
if(pval > 0.05):
    print "Data is normally distributed"
```

However I'd like to add it to the end of a script which creates values and puts them into a dictionary (named 'result') so I dont have to copy the values in manually, but when I use 'result' instead of the numbers for the stats test I get

```
 34 print("%f seconds" % (time.time() - start_time)) #completes measuring time taken for script to run
---> 35 results = stats.normaltest([result])
 36 z,pval = results
 37 if(pval < 0.05):

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'dict' and 'long'
```

Any ideas?

Here is the code for the values going into the dictionary:

```
new_dictionary = {}
count = 0
for m, n in result.items():
    count += 1
    new_dictionary['month_{}'.format(count)] = result
```

m is a file name (as the code draws from a file for each value) and n is the computed value for that file

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to put the value in the dictionary?

Comment: You are putting the dictionary `result` in each place of the `new_dictionary`. That's probably the problem, but without further information, there's no way to tell how to change it. You should probably use either `m` or `n` or both.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: The line that produced the error was not in the original post, making it impossible to figure out what was going wrong.  Next time, please provide a complete example necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are doing a normaltest on a list containing a single dictionary.  You want to do the normaltest on the values of the dictionary, like this:

```
results = stats.normaltest(result.values())
```